# Can I use the description of a table field definition in my application?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssms

When I create tables in SQL Server Management Studio I always add a description for the field I am creating.

Is their a way to access that information to be able to use the description in my application for help text or to use it on the page?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the column description via TSQL:

```
SELECT cast(value as varchar) as ColDescription 
FROM fn_listextendedproperty ('MS_DESCRIPTION','schema', 
   'dbo', 'table', '<tablenamehere>', 'column', '<columnnamehere>');
```

For all the columns in a table that have a description, leave the column null:

```
SELECT objname AS ColName, cast(value as varchar) as ColDescription 
FROM fn_listextendedproperty ('MS_DESCRIPTION','schema', 
   'dbo', 'table', '<tablenamehere>', 'column', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this return the descriptions you are talking about?

```
SELECT objtype, objname, name, value
FROM fn_listextendedproperty('MS_Description', default, default, default, default, default, default);
```